# 'AutoDisposeStreamProvider<T>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'AlwaysAliveProviderListenable<AsyncValue<T>>'

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I want to be able to create a StreamProvider.autoDispose and listen to it inside a StateNotifier.

This way when the StateNotifierProvider.autoDispose is disposed of, the StreamProvider will also be disposed. Otherwise it is left open, which I don’t want.

However, StateNotifierProvider only has access to Ref, not to WidgetRef.
Therefore I cannot create the StreamProvider with .autoDispose, or I get this error:

The argument type 'AutoDisposeStreamProvider' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'AlwaysAliveProviderListenable<AsyncValue>'.

```
final filterList =
    StateNotifierProvider.autoDispose<FilteredListNofifier, List<ServerItem>>(
        (ref) {
  return FilteredListNofifier(ref);
});

class FilteredListNofifier extends StateNotifier<List<ServerItem>> {
  FilteredListNofifier(Ref ref) : super(<ServerItem>[]) {
    ref.listen(filterListStream, (previous, AsyncValue<List<ServerItem>> next) {
      if (next.value != null) {
        state = next.value!;
      }
    });
  }
}

final filterListStream = StreamProvider.autoDispose<List<ServerItem>>((ref) async* {
  yield [];
});
```

Comment: Can you please share your code snippet?

Comment: If you use .autoDispose, every provider it uses must also be .autoDispose.  Or maybe it's the other way around.  But somehow, they have to be in sync.  I didn't quickly find the answer I got from Remi on that to answer a similar question.

Comment: Yes if I use .autoDispose every dependent provider must be the same, this makes sense. But I want to .listen to an .autoDispose provider - how to do this, that is my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `watch` like so:

```
final filterList =
    StateNotifierProvider.autoDispose<FilteredListNofifier, List<ServerItem>>(
        (ref) {
  final a = ref.watch(filterListStream);
  return FilteredListNofifier(a);
});

class FilteredListNofifier extends StateNotifier<List<ServerItem>> {
  FilteredListNofifier(AsyncValue<List<ServerItem>> l) : super(<ServerItem>[]) {
    if (l.asData != null) {
      state = l.asData!.value;
    }
  }
}

final filterListStream = StreamProvider.autoDispose<List<ServerItem>>((ref) async* {
  yield [];
});
```

Comment: Thanks Josteve, this works perfectly. I took a long time to answer as at first I couldn't work out what your approach was doing, I wanted to make sure I understood correctly. Anyway yes, this actually works, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Make your both provider as keep alive and it should work

Don't use normal provider to read autodisposable provider

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).